# (evil-normal-state) seems to have no effect as part of org-agenda-mode-hook

Tags: org-agenda, evil, hooks

I'm attempting to move from Doom Emacs to vanilla Emacs. I've gotten quite used to the keybindings of Doom, so would like to replicate my most used ones in Emacs. I've used evil, evil collection, and evil-org to get my evil keybindings, and I've used general.el and a function call such as the following to set up space as a leader key:

```
(nvmap :keymaps 'override :prefix "SPC"
       "SPC"   '(counsel-M-x :which-key "M-x")
       "."     '(counsel-find-file :which-key "find-file")
       "u"     'universal-argument

       "f"     '(:ignore t :which-key "File")
       "f r"   '(counsel-recentf :which-key "recent-files")
       "f f"   '(counsel-find-file :which-key "find-file")
       <SNIP>)
```

This has worked pretty well for the most part, with the glaring exception of the org-agenda. I use the org-agenda pretty regularly, and I have it set to load when Emacs starts up. While evil-org gives it the vimlike keybindings, my leader key does not function as promised. Instead, hitting space invokes the following:

```
(org-agenda-show-and-scroll-up &optional ARG)
```

While trying to figure out how to get my leader keys to work, I noticed that if I ran the command `(evil-normal-state)` or `(evil-force-normal-state)` my leader keys began working, and the org-agenda buffer functioned as expected, similar to how it does in Doom. I figured I'd try to add a hook and be done with it, but I've tried several permutations of the following, with and without the `(set-buffer "*Org Agenda")` portion, and with both `(evil-normal-state)` and `(evil-force-normal-state)`, and have had no luck.

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook (lambda () (set-buffer "*Org Agenda*") (evil-normal-state)))
(add-hook 'evil-org-agenda-mode-hook (lambda () (set-buffer "*Org Agenda*") (evil-normal-state)))
(eval-after-load 'org-agenda (lambda () (set-buffer "*Org Agenda*") (evil-normal-state)))
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'evil-normal-state)
(advice-add #'evil-force-normal-state :after #'org-agenda-mode)
```

Running these, and various permutations of these, seems to have no effect. My question is why do the hooks not solve my issue? It's clear they're running, I've checked with debug messages that the hooks run, and I've checked by issuing `(evil-normal-state)` as a command that it solves my problem, so why does combining the command with the hook not work as I had expected?

Comment: After playing around with this some, I was able to create my desired behavior with `(evil-set-initial-state 'org-agenda-mode 'normal)`. I still don't understand why the hook wouldn't work, though.